# oracle - Schemas issues when migration from discoverer to OBIEE

Tags: oracle, obiee

I'm working on migrating some reports from Oracle Discoverer to OBIEE. I've already exported the layouts from discoverer to OBIEE. I have all I need in the OBIEE Admin tool now, but when I try to perform this operation:

[image]

I got this message:

[image]

I've read in many forums that this is because of the query ([enter link description here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00923_from_keyword_not_found_where_expected.htm)) but I've executed the query in SQL Developer and all is fine.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: So what is the query it is executing?

Comment: I's just a simple one:

SELECT
*
FROM "SCHEmA"."TABLE1"

Answer (score 1):

I can see from the icon on your object that it is an Opaque View that your trying to run View Data on.

This is probably because of a syntax issue in your opaque view. Make sure the code in the opaque view doesn't end with a semi-colon or slash, that will cause problems. Try eliminating any blank lines, if there are any. However, without knowing exactly the syntax of the code it's impossible to say exactly what the cause is.

It's also possible that there is a connection script attached to the connection pool you are using to View Data, running on connection or before execution with bad syntax.

Otherwise have a look in the Admin Tool log to see if there's more information about what is causing the error. It will usually contain more detailed information than is passed back through the GUI.